# Curve of centers of curvature

Tags: geometry, notation, terminology

I really can't find the English name of the curve of the centers of curvature of a curve. Formulated more precisely:
Suppose $\alpha$ is a regular curve  in $\mathbb{E}^2$ and $||\alpha(t)'||=1$. How do you call $\gamma(t) = \alpha(t)+ \frac{1}{\kappa(t)}N(s)$ in English? I'm following a geometry course in dutch and there this curve is called "centrale kromme" (literal translation: central curve) or "evoluut" in case this would ring any bells...

Thanks!

Comment: [Evolute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute)

Comment: Thank you! I did not expect that these words would resemble this much.

Comment: According to wiki, the notions of evolute and involute were introduced by Christiann Huygens in his work *Horologium oscillatorium sive de motu pendulorum ad horologia aptato demonstrationes geometricae (1673)* and Huygens is a Dutch!